# How can I configure XAMPP to fix this errors?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I just have installed XAMPP in my computer but in the log console it gives to me this following errors:

```
[Apache]    Apache Service detected with wrong path
[Apache]    Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
[Apache]    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
[Apache]    Found Path: "C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
[Apache]    Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
[Apache]    Problem detected!
[Apache]    Port 80 in use by ""C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice" with PID 1632!
[Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
[Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
[Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
[mysql]     Problem detected!
[mysql]     Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini" MySQL55"!
[mysql]     MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
[mysql]     You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
[mysql]     or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

I don't have any idea about how to solve them.

Comment: You need to turn off Skype (or other programs that use port 80) OR you can modify the httpd.conf to use another port for Apache, like 8080.

Comment: And how can I see what applications use port 80? I know that with netstat -o you can see all the ports that are open but I don't know how to interpret the infomation that it's shown there.

Comment: `netstat -a -b` should still work from the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you installed XAMPP Mysql and Apache. If you are going to use XAMPP you need to uninstall Apache and Mysql. That will fix your problem

I am not sure why you installed XAMPP which contains Apache and Mysql and then you install separately Apache and Mysql.

If for some reason you dont want to uninstall Apache and Mysql, you can go to **Windows > Type services.msc and stop service Mysql and apache**

Comment: I uninstall Apache and Mysql and it works perfectly. I installed them before installing XAMPP because I needed them some years ago separated. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

you will try change port 80 of httpd.conf in apache directory:

C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

It´s appear in some lines. Sometimes, it´s after IP, for example, 192.168.1.x:**80**